# Android Binding Adapter using same binding name on same View type but for different purpose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

First, I am new to data binding so please don't judge me for my (possibly dumb) question :). I want to use the same binding name for e.g `app:data` to a `RecyclerView` and bind it to a `ViewModel` field which provides a `List<MyModel>`. But, I want to use a different  Adapter (to inflate different item layout for e.g) for a different instance of `RecyclerView`.

```
// For RecyclerView 1
@BindingAdapter("app:data")
fun setData(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<MyModel>?) {
    data?.let {
        recyclerView.adapter = RV1Adapter(data)
    }
}

// For RecyclerView 2
@BindingAdapter("app:data")
fun setData(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<MyModel>?) {
    data?.let {
        recyclerView.adapter = RV2Adapter(data)
    }
}
```

On a layout for e.g

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rcv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:data="${viewModel.data}"/>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rcv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:data="${viewModel.data}"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Should I use different binding name? (I'm not using this approach before because it will be a little bit messy I think)

Or how is the 'correct' way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same binding adapter tag as both `setData()` methods have the same signature/parameters, so in layout it can't decide which one to use.

But instead you can use a single method, and differ between both `RecyclerViews` with their `id`

```
@BindingAdapter("app:data")
fun setData(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<MyModel>?) {
    data?.let {
        if (recyclerView.id == R.id.rcv1)
            recyclerView.adapter = RV1Adapter(data)

        else if (recyclerView.id == R.id.rcv2)
            recyclerView.adapter = RV2Adapter(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just want to confirm, this is a good practice right?

Comment: Regarding view id comparison, yes it's efficient practice.. think of calculator app.. you can have a single method for all the number buttons, and just differentiate between them using their ids instead of creating a method for every single button... Regarding the `BindingAdapter` of course yes this is what documentation says.

Comment: Thank you for your help, very appreciated.

Comment: for this solution, you will need to modify BindingAdapter whenever you want to use that method (app:data) for other recyclerview. Example: if you have another recyclerview with id rcv3. What do you do?

Answer (score 2):

I have never applied your solution. I usually create an observer for the data of ViewModel in Fragment and pass it to Adapter.

But I think we still have a solution for your problem. I don't know how you implemented your Adapter. I assume that your adapter is extending from ListAdapter.
So instead of initializing your adapter in Binding Adapter, we will initialize it in the Fragment and assign it to Recyclerview. Like this:

```
// onCreateView method 
val adapter = RV2Adapter()
dataBinding.rcv.adapter = adapter
```

and then in the Binding Adapter, we will do like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:data")
fun setData(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<MyModel>?) {
    data?.let {
        recyclerView.adapter.submitList(data)
    }
}
```

If your adapter isn't extending from ListAdapter. You can create a setter method in its and pass the list of data.

```
@BindingAdapter("app:data")
    fun setData(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<MyModel>?) {
        data?.let {
            recyclerView.adapter.setData(data)
            recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataChanged()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still have a question. My adapters is extending `RecyclerView.Adapter`. How should I know to convert the `recyclerView.adapter` to `RV1Adapter` or `RV2Adapter`? Or should I create a base class for that adapters to extend (which the base class also extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`) and cast the `recyclerView.adapter` to that base class? Thanks

Comment: In the Binding Adapter, you can check the type of adapter. recyclerView.adapter is RV1Adapter ....  But I think you should extend your adapter from ListAdapter. Check more about androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter to know what advances it has. And in this case, you just need to call recyclerView.adapter.submitList(data)